# Google apps script UrlFetchApp error "Access not granted or expired"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-app-maker

I have created an service account to access domain user's files in google drive to change sharing settings.

Here is the app script code:

```
`  if(service.hasAccess){

        var fileId = activity.events[0].parameters[6].value;
        var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/'+fileId+'/permissions'
        var body = {
          'value': 'domain.com',
          'type': 'domain.com',
          'role': 'writer'
        };
                Logger.log("done");
         var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          resource: body,
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
          }
        });`
```

I can see "done" text in the logs dialog box. So i think the service has access to users drive. But still raising the same error. Am i missing something here? any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Your `Logger.log("done")` statement is _BEFORE_ the URL Fetch, so it's going to log that anyway.

Comment: You can do most Drive file sharing actions through the built-in [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/), without having to use the Google Drive API.

Comment: @Diego But i am accessing to other users google drive files. So i think i shoud use a service account.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know App Maker provides your an opportunity to connect API without direct calls. You can open settings page, scroll to the bottom and add advanced service **Drive API**:

[image: app settings]

[image: select Drive API]

Then you will be able to use Apps Script Drive service: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/

Details about connection Drive API to App Maker you can find here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive

Comment: I have already tried this method. But it raised "access denied" error. I have been trying the solve this issue for 3 days with no luck.

Comment: Did you enable this API at Google Cloud platform? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services

Comment: I enabled the API at Google Cloud Platform after you noticed. But i still have the same error...